# Parallel spatial processing based on GDAL/OGR with spatial filter using python?

Tags: python, filter, spatial, gdal, ogr

I'm applying a spatial filter sequentially with GDAL/OGR in Python in order to calculate a point density:

```
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(xCoord, yCoord)
searchArea = point.Buffer(searchBuffer)
layer.SetSpatialFilter(searchArea)
density[i, j] = layer.GetFeatureCount()
```

But now I want parallelize my code, to improve the performance.

How can I process spatial data in parallel with GDAL/OGR in Python? Especially, can I apply a spatial filter on a data source in parallel?

I want to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor`

Comment: Has somebody already solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

GDAL does not support parallel operations on one Dataset. Either you will have to open it multiple times, or, otherwise, if you need a high performance implementation, you will have to implement it yourself. `SetSpatialFilter` is not the best way to do it anyway, as it will require iterating over the features for every pair `(i, j)`.

Load all the features in an R-Tree, then loop over `(i, j)`. This is a standard algorithm with existing implementations in Python.